# ctypes.c_int.from_address does not work in RStudio

Tags: python, rstudio

I am trying to count references to an object in Python using the RStudio. I use following function:

```
 ctypes.c_int.from_address(id(an_object)).value
```

This work perfectly in Pycharm and Jupyter as shown bellow:

[image]

and the result in the RStudio is:

[image]

The question is why the result is not correct in RStudio and how to fix it?

I also tried to use

```
sys.getrefcount
```

function, but It does not work in RStudio too!

I did it without using "id" function as shown below:

[image]

[image]

But the result in RStudio is not correct! Sometimes It may happen in PyCharm(I did not see, Perhaps  no guarantee) But in RStudio something is wrong completely!

Why this is important?! And why I care about it.

Consider following example:

[image]

Sometimes it is important to know about "a" before change "b".

The big problem in RStudio is the result increases randomly! But in PyCharm and other Python tools I did not see that happen.

I am not an expert on this so if I am wrong on it correct me please.

Comment: Why are you expecting any particular result from this code?  There's no guarantee that the result of `id()` has any particular meaning, and even on Python implementations where it returns a memory address, there's no guarantee that the value at that address is the refcount.

Comment: @jasonharper, Sometimes it is important to know about reference count. You could see Deep Dive(an Udemy tutorial) part one.

Comment: @jasonharper, I did it without using "id" function too. I am not an expert on it but I can not understand the results in RStudio completely! No guarantee is far from not work correctly at all!

Answer (score 0):

the problem seems to be just that r-studio spams a lot of other references to the objects you create. In the same Python version you  would otherwise see no divergence there.

That said, you are definitely taking the wrong approach there: either you alias some data structure expecting it to be mutable "under your feet", or you should refrain from making changes at all to data that "may" be in use in other parts of your code (notebook). That is the reasoning Pandas, for example, have been changing all default operations on dataframe from "inplace" to return a new copy, despite the memory cost of doing that.

Other than that, as stated in the comments, the reason this is so hidden in Python - to the point you have to use ctypes (you could also use the higher level `gc` module, actually), is that *it should not matter*.

There are other things you could do - like, create objects that use Locks so that they don't allow changes if they are in use in some other critical place - that would be higher level and reproducible.